# How to work with my remote git repository or how to sync it with local folder?

Tags: git, github

I am creating small project and using git to share my code (usually for it).

You know some files are being deleted, some are new... I am pushing files to my repository ~ once a day. I just realized, that remote repository contains all files (even if they are removed in my local repository).

I don't know all functions of github ofcourse and using only few feautures so I am asking for the help.

I used [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Git/article.html) tutorial to learn how to work with github.

I was pushing files to my remote repository using this:

```
git add .
git commit -m "some comment for current push"
git push my-repository my-branch
```

It is working, but it seems to me I am doing something wrong, because, as I said, I found files, which are removed from my local repository.

I think I need something like sync-ing local repository with remote repository: files, which are deleted on local machine will be deleted, other files, if they are changed are pushed to the repository.

Comment: I think you should read a tutorial on git first.

Comment: You need to `git rm <file>`, then `git commit`. As @musicmatze suggests, this is covered in most Git tutorials.

Comment: @musicmatze As I said, I used [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Git/article.html) tutorial. As you see, there are 52 paragraphs with information. I am new to it, so it is impossible for me to find usefull information in it. Can you provide link to the tutorial, which will help 'so dumb' me to understand how to work with git.

Comment: @Chris thanks. I read one of tutorials and realized that `git rm` will delete files from my local machine... =/ I answered to @musicmatze, but you can read my comment two. Same question: can you suggest some tutorial, which wouldn't be hard and I will understand how to work with git after reading it?

Comment: This tutorial looks really good. I mentioned learning git as you said you used the tutorial to learn with _github_, which isn't quite the same. You should read until chapter 14, I guess, to understand what to do.

Comment: @musicmatze. It is good, reading this tutorial, I at least know how to 'upload' files to the remote repository (maybe it is not clear for me, because my english is not too good ofc).

Comment: @SharikovVladislav, the tutorial you link looks good but very long. I like [Think like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/), because it doesn't shy away from Git's internals. Anything that *hides* what Git is really doing does more harm than good in my opinion...

Comment: @Chris why it does more harm? At least, it is possible to show many lines of source code to somebody (impossible to use sites like `ideone.com` in that case). + review code changes + forking and merging popular projects (which is still problem for me :D ).

Comment: @SharikovVladislav, basically, Git is very complex. When you hide its complexity (e.g. in the GitHub for Windows or GitHub for OSX applications) I believe that you make it (a) more dangerous for new users, because they wield a power they don't understand, and (b) less powerful for experienced users, because the tool doesn't reflect what they do. Embrace the complexity with the `git` command-line tools or something like [SourceTree](http://sourcetreeapp.com/), which manages to be a good GUI while not hiding the complexity.

Comment: @Chris, Do you want to say, that it is better to use something like SourceTree? I tried what you said: `git rm <file>` and `git commit` after, but id didn't worked. I will read tutorial, that you gave above, if you say it can help. Hope it will help.

Comment: @SharikovVladislav, it is my opinion that hiding Git's complexity hurts developers. Yes, using something like SourceTree (or the default `git` command-line suite) is better because it doesn't hide the complexity.

Comment: `(or the default git command-line suite)` — but I am using this. Or not? I downloaded Git from [this page](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git). I am working with console now. As you suggested, I had installed SourceTree. It is more comfortable to work with it, I think :)